# Is there any similar application like this one written in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I want to develop a website in Which it has a similar functionalities like this one:  http://www.regeltante.nl/  and this one  http://www.regeltante.nl/vraagaanbod/default_small_.asp? I want to it in a different location. As I can see it is Developed in ASP? (If I'm correct) and I want it too build it in PHP. I have read the documentation of Google Maps Javascript API Basics V3 but I do not know if I'm in the right course here. Do you have any similar demo for this in PHP? That could be a big help.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What portion are you having difficulty with? It sounds like the Google maps integration. I'd say "yes", you are on the right track following the Google Maps API. Keep going with it and let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: @Mark I'm following this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html tutorial when I get stuck and I have the posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568211/xml-data-cant-be-displayed-from-mysql-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks pretty basic to me. Not sure how much experience you have, but all you need is a database with your map objects (name, description, image for the icon, lan/lat position to place it on the right spot) and the just hook it all up with php and create some javascript code that polls the google api. http://econym.org.uk/gmap/ has lot's of examples to get your started, and here is an official google tutorial about this topic: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html