# enable error reporting for apache server in linux

Tags: php, linux, apache

I've created a php file in my localhost, but when I tried to test it I got this message from navigator :

> ## Server error
>
> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   `http://localhost/ex_exam_2012/affiche_note.php?cin=SY3422`. It may be
>   down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

normally apache server should show me where there is the probelm, in Windows I never got this problem, but this is my first time to test a php file in Linux, I Gooled about itg and I founs this question to enable displaying errors :

> [PHP production server - turn on error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824282/php-production-server-turn-on-error-messages)

So I changed this to values :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

And :

```
display_errors = On
```

but I still have that probelm, how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

That's just a generic message that tells you there was a problem.  You need to look at Apache's `error_log` file to find out what happened.  It's often found in `/var/log/apache`, but different Linux distributions sometimes change the location of this error log.

Comment: I want apache to show me the error in navigator as in Windows

Comment: What's "navigator"?  Are you talking about the web browser?  It won't show you internal server errors like that in the browser (even in Windows).

Comment: for example if there is some error in some variable declaration, when I test the page he shows me that there is a probelm with that variable and the line where there is the ptoblem