# posting data from an html page to a php file and redirect from the php file to the homepage

Tags: php, html

I want the data to be posted into the datahouse.php which will now submit the data to the server and redirect to Index page without showing the datahouse.php file on page..

### register.html

```
<form method="POST" action="DataHouse.php">
<input type="text" name="username" value="tempapilogin" /><br>
<input type="password" name="password" value="aF4YMjuQ" /><br>
<input type="text" required name="name" placeholder="Full Name" /><br>
<input type="email" required name="email" placeholder="EMail Address" /><br>
Gender:
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" >
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio-mini-1" value="MALE" />
        <label for="radio-mini-1">MALE</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio-mini-2" value="FEMALE" />
        <label for="radio-mini-2">FEMALE</label>
        </fieldset>     
Birthday: <input type="date" required name="birth_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
Phone Number: <input placeholder="02xxxxxxxx" type="tel" name="phone_number" />
Facebook ID: <input type="email" name="facebookid" />
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Below is the php file to post the data to the server and will then have to redirect to the index.html page.

### datahouse.php

```
<?php
//Index.html page to redirect to-->
header("Location: c:\Users\Selorm\Desktop\Maxwell-Internship @ Nandimobile\connect\Index.html");

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init();

//create array of data to be posted
array{$post_items[] = 'Username='.strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$post_items[] = 'Password='.strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$post_items[] = 'Email='.strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$post_items[] = 'Gender='.strip_tags($_POST['gender']);
$post_items[] = 'Birthday='.strip_tags($_POST['birth_date']);
$post_items[] = 'Phone Number='.strip_tags($_POST['phone_number']);
$post_items[] = 'Facebook ID='.strip_tags($_POST['facebookid']);}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$birth_date = $_POST['birth_date'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$facebookid = $_POST['facebookid'];

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//set options and set data to be posted
curl_setopt_array($curl_connection, array(
 CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
 CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
 username => 'username',
 password => 'password',
 name => 'name',
 email => 'email',
 gender => 'gender',
 birth_date => 'birth_date',
 phone_number => 'phone_number',
 facebookid => 'facebookid' )
 ));

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
$result = json_decode($json);
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
{
 echo $key. ':' ;
}
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . 
curl_error($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Put your header to php file and it will redirect!

Comment: Whats the problem here?

Comment: Better you can use Ajax POST.

Comment: @SuryaS There is no "better", since a PHP script will do just as fine. Only use AJAX POST if you really don't want to use PHP.

Comment: @SergeiBeregov it is already there but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Parrotmaster : You can send an ajax request to a PHP page, it does the same job, but without two useless redirects

Comment: @michael92 Your "header("Location: c:\Users\Selorm\Desktop\Maxwell-Internship @ Nandimobile\connect\Index.html");" sends the user to another page BEFORE performing all the code. You need to put it at the END, otherwise it sends the user away before doing all the other PHP.

Comment: @JonathanRomer the problem is i have a register page and the input fields on the register page should be posted to a php file which will submit the data into the server and then redirect to a different html page based on the fact that the data is posted into the server.

Comment: @Parrotmaster it was at the end before but when i submit it only shows a blank page with datahouse.php in the address bar not knowing whether the data is been posted or not

Comment: @Pascamel: Ajax doesn't work when Javascript is disabled or otherwise unavailable. Hard as it may be to believe, certain types of browsers don't even support Javascript. Don't lose sight of usability.

Comment: @Herbert, OP tagged the question under jQuery, so I'm assuming he can use JS ;)

Comment: @Pascamel what will be the codes in that case...im new to everything im doing now anyways..

Comment: @michael92 Try using the simpler echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.yourwebsite.nl/page.html">' That I posted. You can use the same URL.

Comment: @Parrotmaster is that in any way going to check whether the data is posted before it redirects to the address in the URL..

Comment: @Herbert im asking if you could go through the whole code and verify if that's what it is supposed to be?

Comment: @michael92 No, it's just a standard redirect. I don't know how to tell you this but.....I'm afraid you're gonna have to actually do something yourself :(

Comment: @Parrotmaster..i appreciate the help you're giving me but i really need all your comments, corrections and suggestions

Comment: I made an edit to remove the JQuery tag, since the question is not related to JQuery.

Comment: @Parrotmaster...i have pasted thw whole link at http://pastebin.com/iD0TJAhJ would like you to look at the whole code and then help from there...

Comment: [edit] your question to tell us what problem your having. Is it not redirecting, is it not posting the data. What exactly is the problem you need help with?

Comment: @herbert..it is not redirecting neither is it posting the data

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the problem is that the page relocates, but doesn't post anything.

datahouse.php redirects as soon as it encounters

```
header("Location: c:\Users\Selorm\Desktop\Maxwell-Internship @ Nandimobile\connect\Index.html");
```

Move that to the end and DO NOT OUTPUT **ANYTHING** BEFORE IT. If you echo anything, you'll get an error telling you that headers have already been sent.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. I would've posted this same answer if the person asking the question would've been clearer about what he wanted.

Comment: @Herbert...that is what i beleive is going on...so i want you to figure out if the php file code is correct....

Comment: @Parrotmaster ,i want to post the data on the register.html page but first the datahouse.php file should take the data and now post it into the server and upon the response from the server...if successful it should now redirect to the index.html page

Comment: @Parrotmaster: Spend enough time on SO and you get a knack for guessing what the question _actually_ is. Sometimes it's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: There's an `echo` statement in one of your loops. The page won't redirect if you output anything before the header. You're getting a blank page because you don't have error reporting turned on. Also `header("Location: index.html");` _should_ be sufficient even on localhost.

Comment: @Herbert...how would i turn on error reporting ...?can u help me out based on the submitted code..

Comment: [How do I turn on error reporting to find the source of problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1824352/911182)

Comment: @Herbert the "How do i turn on error reporting to find the source of problems?"...i didn't really understand what it is doing

Comment: Try [PHP Error Reporting](http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/qt/php_error_reporting.htm). Add the two lines of code to the beginning of your PHP script.

Comment: Remember. You can't output _anything_ from the datahouse.php page if you want it to redirect. That includes echo, print_r, var_dump, print, or anything else that displays something on the page. After your data is sent via cURL, your code is showing the results. That's fine for testing the code to make sure it works, but the page won't redirect as long as that stuff is in there.

Comment: @Herbert,so what do you suggest i do

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a redirect to a URL visible on some web server.

You cannot redirect the client to an arbitrary filepath on the server's hard disk.

Comment: @Slaks..im using an arbitrary filepath the server's harddisk because it's not yet online....

Comment: @michael92 In that case a redirect would still work. If you're using a local PHP server your URL would look like so: "http://localhost/yourwebsite/page.html" or "http://127.0.0.1/yourwebsite/page.html"

Comment: @Parrotmaster i have the credentials to connect to the server into which i will post the data into..i have to now decipher whether the posted data is really posted into the server and if it is posted then i should now be redirected to the index.html page im talking about

Comment: guys help me fix this stuff im not done yet...@Parrotmaster,@herbert

Comment: @michael92: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: @SLaks ...what dev tools are you talking about?

Comment: @michael92: Chrome Developer Tools (F12) or Firebug.  Look in the console and network tabs.