# How to turn on PHP error reporting for a single script?

Tags: php, debugging

I was given the task to upload a script on some old production server and, as expected, many things don't work.

I wanted to know if it was possible to turn on error reporting for a single script without having access to the actual `php.ini` file.

I've tried this: [PHP production server - turn on error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824282/php-production-server-turn-on-error-messages), using:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

But that won't work on this server. If I trigger an error, e.g.:

```
public static funtion myfunc() { … }
```

Or I try to use an undefined function, e.g.:

```
password_verify();
```

I end up staring at a blank screen. I also don't have access to any (useful) logs. I've also tried this: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php), but I don't have access to any `.htaccess` file either.

Is there another way to enable this feature? Or is it possible to *catch* critical errors  and display their information, programatically? The server's PHP version is 5.3 (5.3.28).

Comment: perhaps this answer can help? -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/18208549/1407478

Comment: Let me try it (the ftp is crap, too).

Comment: is the error log writable by the server?

Comment: I think it is, but I can't know for sure, I can't even ssh to it.

Answer (score 1):

From [your posted link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824282/php-production-server-turn-on-error-messages), do you have try to change

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1)
```

Cheers

Comment: Yes, I tried that instead of 'On' before, but that doesn't work either. It's in fact commented above it, it's the first one I tried.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I stumbled across this problem on a client's server when the guy in charge of Apache was on a very different timezone and I didn't want to wait 8 hours. If you put your code in a try catch block, like so:

```
try {
   //your test code here
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

That should solve a lot of your problems.

Comment: I tried this but it still only gives me a blank page with error 500 reported in console.

Answer (score 0):

You might be out of luck if the server has display_errors configured in the apache config with a 'php_admin_value' flag. That prevents override with a htaccess or ini_set functions.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

You might be able to grab the error with your own error handler function using set_error_handler, but it has some limitations too. It can can only grab warnings and user defined errors.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php